# Trying to add data into database but its not adding in table

Tags: c#

I am tried to add some data into the database but it not adding inside the database table ,But it didnt show any exception also.I dont know whats the problem

```
      try
      {
       SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework");
       con.Open();                       
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Store(Item,Description,Expences) values('pen','blue','10')", con);
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       con.Close();
      }
```

My App Config file

```
     [![<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>   
  <add name="StoreContext" connectionString="data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /></connectionStrings>
</configuration>][1]][1]
```

My Table

```
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Store] (
   [Id]          INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
   [Item]        VARCHAR (20)  NOT NULL,
   [Description] VARCHAR (100) NULL,
   [Expences]    INT           NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
 );
```

Comment: If you are using entity framework then why you are inserting data using SqlCommand

Comment: No errors it showing

Comment: Actually i tried both ways both also not working

Comment: If your using Visual studio enable the throw exception from DEBUG->EXCEPTION and see any exception is throwing or not.

Comment: already its enabled its not showing any exception.@Aravind Sivam

Comment: Who down voted my question ...please solve my issue and down vote it.I dont care about downvote. without giving solution dont down vote it

Answer (score 1):

Try below code, below code is written without using any tool so please try to adjust the code.

```
try
{  
            DbContext xyz = new DbContext();
            Store oStore = new Store();
            oStore.Item = "pen";
            oStore.Description = "blue";
            oStore.Expences = 10;
            xyz.Stores.Add(oStore);
            xyz.SaveChanges(); // never forgot to do SaveChanges  
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
       MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Already i tried this ...for this also no errors ..but not stored in database

Comment: check your connection string then may be it is pointing to any other database in which you are checking

Comment: ` Store accountdata = new Store()
                    {
                        Description = Convert.ToString(desc.Text),
                        Expences = expences,
                        Item = Convert.ToString(item.Content)
                    };

                    StoreContext sc = new StoreContext();
                    sc.Stores.Add(accountdata);
                    sc.SaveChanges();
`  I tried this my database name is Database1

Comment: Checked connection string also its same also

Comment: put a break point on your code check every steps is executing or not,
because there is no problem in code as I can see

Comment: even i checked that also its executing all the lines without any problem. Store class object contains value also

Comment: I tried all the possible ways but still i didnt get a solution .

Comment: Do you have any BEFORE INSERT trigger on the Store table that could be preventing the write?

Comment: Now i deleted my database and run it...now it showing exception ** A file activation error occurred. The physical file name '\Database1.mdf' may be incorrect**  so connection sting also not a problem

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your request, Expences is a integer :

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Store(Item,Description,Expences) values('pen','blue',10)", con);
```

Comment: This should never cause a issue. You can try for yourself. Though it's a good idea not to pass string as integer.

Comment: now i tried this also but  now also it not adding into database @Rahul